# count occurrences in a string similar to run length encoding c#

Tags: c#, string

Say I have a string like

```
MyString1 = "ABABABABAB";
MyString2 = "ABCDABCDABCD";
MyString3 = "ABCAABCAABCAABCA";
MyString4 = "ABABACAC";
MyString5 = "AAAAABBBBB";
```

and I need to get the following output

```
Output1 = "5(AB)";
Output2 = "3(ABCD)";
Output3 = "4(ABCA)";
Output4 = "2(AB)2(AC)";
Output5 = "5(A)5(B)";
```

I have been looking at RLE but I can't figure out how to do the above.
The code I have been using is

```
public static string Encode(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"(.)\1*", delegate(Match m)
    {
        return string.Concat(m.Value.Length, "(", m.Groups[1].Value, ")");
    });
}
```

This works for Output5 but can I do the other Outputs with Regex or should I be using something like Linq?

The purpose of the code is to display MyString in a simple manner as I can get MyString being up to a 1000 characters generally with a pattern to it.
I am not too worried about speed.

Comment: It really depends on where you determine what starts a group.. How does output 1 know it must repeat `AB` where 3 must repeat `ABCA` and not `ABC`?

Comment: why is `Output5 = "5(A)5(B)";` and not `Output5 = "1(AAAAA)1(BBBBB)";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Non-`Regex` way given the data that you provided.  I'm not sure of any edge cases, right now, that would trip this code up.  If so, I'll update accordingly.

```
string myString1 = "ABABABABAB";
string myString2 = "ABCDABCDABCD";
string myString3 = "ABCAABCAABCAABCA";
string myString4 = "ABABACAC";
string myString5 = "AAAAABBBBB";

CountGroupOccurrences(myString1, "AB");
CountGroupOccurrences(myString2, "ABCD");
CountGroupOccurrences(myString3, "ABCA");
CountGroupOccurrences(myString4, "AB", "AC");
CountGroupOccurrences(myString5, "A", "B");
```

CountGroupOccurrences() looks like the following:

```
private static void CountGroupOccurrences(string str, params string[] patterns)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    while (str.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (string pattern in patterns)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int index = str.IndexOf(pattern); 
            while (index > -1)
            {
                count++;
                str = str.Remove(index, pattern.Length);
                index = str.IndexOf(pattern); 
            }
            result += string.Format("{0}({1})", count, pattern);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Results:

```
5(AB)
3(ABCD)
4(ABCA)
2(AB)2(AC)
5(A)5(B)
```

### UPDATE

This worked with `Regex`

```
private static void CountGroupOccurrences(string str, params string[] patterns)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    foreach (string pattern in patterns)
    {
        result += string.Format("{0}({1})", Regex.Matches(str, pattern).Count, pattern);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: @astroas The patterns need to be determined during run time?

Comment: If you want pattern detection, then you're actually writing your own compression algorithm. Good luck with that...

Answer (score 2):

Using RLE with single characters is easy, there never is an overlap between matches. If the number of characters to repeat is variable, you'd have a problem:

```
AAABAB
```

Could be:

```
3(A)BAB
```

Or

```
AA(2)AB
```

You'll have to define what rules you want to apply. Do you want the absolute best compression? Does speed matter?

I doubt Regex can look forward and select "the best" combination of matches - So to answer your question I would say "no".

Comment: I would prefer Output to be 2(A)2(AB). I am not after the best compression just a way of simplifying MyString and not concerned about speed. MyString examples are not many characters but they can be up to 1000 characters.

Answer (score 1):

RLE is of no help here - it's just an extremely simple compression where you repeat a single code-point a given number of times. This was quite useful for e.g. game graphics and transparent images ("next, there's 50 transparent pixels"), but is not going to help you with variable-length code-points.

Instead, have a look at Huffman encoding. Expanding it to work with variable-length codewords is not exactly cheap, but it's a start - and it saves a lot of space, if you can afford having the table there.

But the first thing you have to ask yourself is, what are you optimizing for? Are you trying to get the shortest possible string on output? Are you going for speed? Do you want as few code-words as possible, or do you need to balance the repetitions and code-word counts in some way? In other words, what are you actually trying to do? :))

To illustrate this on your "expected" return values, Output4 results in a longer string than MyString4. So it's not the shortest possible representation. You're not trying for the least amounts of code-words either, because then Output5 would be `1(AAAAABBBBB)`. Least amount of repetitions is of course silly (it would always be `1(...)`). You're not optimizing for low overhead either, because that's again broken in Output4.

And whichever of those are you trying to do, I'm thinking it's not going to be possible with regular expressions - those only work for regular languages, and encoding like this doesn't seem all that regular to me. The decoding does, of course; but I'm not so sure about the encoding.